# Solving Three Part Ratio

Tags: algebra-precalculus, ratio

I came across this question today and my Math 20-2 instructor expects that I know how to solve it. I have never seen a ratio like this before, I am usually using a ratio with 2 parts ($a:b = c:d$ or $\frac{a}{b}=\frac{c}{d}$). Here's how it goes:

$5:2:x = y:14:21$

I'm thinking that it needs to be changed into a linear equation? The answer key says $x = 3$ and $y = 35$. Any ideas on how to solve this? Also, what would this ratio be called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All they're saying is that you have three pairs in ratio, not two.  Using your second version, that means that
$$\frac{5}{y} = \frac{2}{14} = \frac{x}{21}$$
As long as you have one "complete" fraction, you're good to go.

Comment: Thanks so much! I was making it harder than it actually was.